# How to import event log files data in to SQL Table Automatically

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

Currently, I am importing the event log file data into SQL table
manually.

But I want to do this process automatically.

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-log-cube-processing-in-ssas-041510

Comment: How are you doing manually, and what have you tried so far? Do you have experience with SSIS?

Comment: From SSMS, manually importing the file to the sql table.